# Can %~n1 be Used in the Registry?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, wildcards

I am currently trying to integrate a program into my shell, the program in question is a CLI tool that has multiple options for files passed to it. I know that it is possible to run *'code'* in the registry to an extent. At least what seems to have similar syntax to batch scripting. An example is the use of `%1` if you want to pass a file to a given program. The program in question unpacks a certain file type, if I use the commandline directly I can use the following code to extract the contents to a folder that has the same name as the infile I supply:

`Decompiler.exe -i %* -o "%~n1"`

I don't know the exact terminology for the `%~n1` wildcard, but I do know other uses for it such as `%~nx1` *(**n**ame and e**x**tension of argument 1)*. With that aside, if I use this same wildcard in the registry it outputs to a folder labeled `%~n1`. Is it possible to use this wildcard in the registry to get the same effect as if it were used in CLI, or is there an equivalent alternative?

Comment: It is important to note that this is not a wildcard at all. It also is a Batch feature, so I doubt it’ll work.

Comment: I am quite sure you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `%~n1` is called
[Variable Substitutions](http://cplusplus.bordoon.com/cmd_exe_variables.html).

This is handled by CMD (`cmd.exe`) which also runs `.bat` files,
but is *not* handled when included in the registry.

You should create a `.bat` file that does whatever task you need and that
includes Variable Substitutions as required,
then call this file from the registry.

Comment: Unfortunate, I was already using a script before. I'll just resume using it, my goal was to have a more streamlined system for how I use this tool. Thank you for the information.